# what is the difference between StringBuffer appen and insert?

Tags: java, string, stringbuffer

In my java code i am using

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
String str = "";
sb.append(str + "abc"); //??
sb.insert(0,(str + "abc")); //??
```

any one tell me what is difference between this `sb.append(str + "abc");` and `sb.insert(0,(str + "abc"));`

Comment: Have you read the Javadoc for both methods?

Comment: Since your sb String value is empty, technichally the String is the same, but both methods fullfill a different function.

Comment: Prepending `str` doesn't change anything here, you may as well drop it from the question.

Comment: "Append" and "insert": the words themselves already have a difference and the fact that you provide an index with `insert` should be a huge giveaway.

Comment: Please don't use StringBuffer, it was replaced by StringBuilder more than ten years ago.

Comment: Don't use `StringBuffer`/`StringBuilder` and string concatenation simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, as `String str = "";` you cannot see difference but there is.

- **First one append at the end.**
- **Second one insert at the begining.**

---

Look at this code snippets:

## 1 append:

```
String str = "abc";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("123");
sb.append("abc"); // str = "123abc"
//                             ↑ abc is appended at the end of sb
```

From the API:

[`append(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#append%28java.lang.String%29):

> Appends the string representation of the char array argument to this sequence.

---

## 2 insert:

```
String str = "abc";
StringBuilder sb0 = new StringBuilder("123");
sb.insert(0, str); // str = "abc123"
//                           ↑ abc is inserted at position 0 of sb0
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder("123");
sb.insert(1, str); // str = "1abc23"
//                            ↑ abc is inserted at position 1 of sb1
StringBuilder sb3 = new StringBuilder("123");
sb.insert(2, str); // str = "12abc3"
//                             ↑ abc is inserted at position 2 of sb2
StringBuilder sb4 = new StringBuilder("123");
sb.insert(3, str); // str = "123abc"
//                              ↑ abc is inserted at position 3 of sb2
```

So... We can extrapolate than: `StringBuilder.append == StringBuilder.insert(length)`

[`insert(int offset, String str)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html#insert%28int,%20java.lang.String%29)

> Inserts the string representation of the char array argument into this
> sequence.
> The characters of the array argument are inserted into the contents of this sequence **at the position indicated by offset.** The length of this sequence increases by the length of the argument.

Comment: The output of `sb.insert(0,(str + "abc")); // str = abc123` should be `123abc` assuming sb is a fresh object.

Answer (score 1):

From the [doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html#insert(int,%20char))

`appends()`like name sounds adds to the end of the datatype whereas `inserts()` inserts one string into another

Example from the doc,

> if z refers to a string buffer object whose current contents are
>   "start", then the method call z.append("le") would cause the string
>   buffer to contain "startle", whereas z.insert(4, "le") would alter the
>   string buffer to contain "starlet".

In your example, the offset is 0 so it will insert at the beginning of the string.

> Note: In general, if sb refers to an instance of a StringBuffer, then
>   sb.append(x) has the same effect as sb.insert(sb.length(), x).

Answer (score 1):

The append() method appends the string to the end but The insert( ) method inserts one string into another at given offset. In append() method have single parameter, that parameter value append at end of the string. In insert() method have 2 parameters one is offset(int type) and another one is value for insert.

Example for append() method:-

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
sb.append("abc");
sb.append("123");
```

Output: abc123

Example for insert() method:-

```
StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
```

sb.append("abc");
sb.insert(2,"123");

Output: ab123c